# Android built-in command line

Tags: android, ant, javac

I create android project with command:

```
android create project --target android-3 --path name --package com.name --activity name
```

build and install with commands:

```
ant debug
adb install -r bin/name-debug.apk
```

its takes 11 sec. In Eclipse create project from source of this project clean and run takes 2-3 seconds.

How to build and run faster in command line?

Comment: try remove some tasks about remove .class